# narrow xdocument in c#

Tags: c#, xml

Is there any way to to cut off some part of xDocument and still getting xDocument? By cutting off I mean keeping selected node.
I have XML like this:

```
<something 1>
    <object>
        Name="The only object I need"
        <lev1>
            <lev2>
                Name= "Attribute I need"
            </lev2>
            <lev2>
                Name= "Attribute I also need"
            </lev2>
        </lev1>
    </object>
    <object>
        Name="Thing I want to remove"
        <lev1>
            <lev2>
                Name= "useless attribute"
            </lev2>
            <lev2>
                Name= "second useless atribute"
            </lev2>
        </lev1>
    </object>
</something 1>
```

I need xDocument object containing only object with Name= "Attribute I need". I know it's easy, but I can't find it.
Edit:
I'm talking about a lot of really immense XML files. Therefore I can't just select something to remove.

Comment: And now you've changed the question in a way that makes my answer seem invalid - please don't do that. Next, your XML probably *doesn't* look like that - I suspect you actually have XML attributes, rather than text nodes of the form `Name = "The only object I need"`. I would suggest you revert your question to the previous version, and I'll edit my answer to address the more general aspect.

Comment: Your question is also pretty unclear in terms of what would happen if only *one* of the nested elements were required. Are you *only* trying to prune elements from the top-level, or prune all kinds of bits of the tree?

Comment: Overally I need all the names in lev2 inside object with name = "The only object I need". I tried xdoc.Elements().Where(x => x.Attribute(xmlns + "Name").Value.ToString() == "The only object I need").FirstOrDefault(); but I get error like "x variable wasn't set to being called", translated from german...

Comment: That's very, very unclear. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and put a *lot* more effort into the question. Give a suitable XML input document and expected output, along with what you've tried already. Make sure you're clear about what you want in the case where some grandchild elements need to be retained and others don't.

Comment: I hadn't even spotted the bit about your error message being in German. I think you should be able to see I was losing patience with the lack of clarity long before that comment though... certainly no racism involved, but I don't like having time wasted by questions that change and are unclear. There should be no need to use `IQueryable<T>` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean you want only the first child node? Yes, that's simple using the [`Remove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357554(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method:

```
doc.Root.Elements().Skip(1).Remove();
```

Sample:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var doc = new XDocument(new XElement ("root",
            new XElement("child1", new XElement("grandchild1")),
            new XElement("child2", new XElement("grandchild2"))));

        Console.WriteLine("Document before:");
        Console.WriteLine(doc);

        doc.Root.Elements().Skip(1).Remove();

        Console.WriteLine("Document after:");
        Console.WriteLine(doc);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Document before:
<root>
  <child1>
    <grandchild1 />
  </child1>
  <child2>
    <grandchild2 />
  </child2>
</root>
Document after:
<root>
  <child1>
    <grandchild1 />
  </child1>
</root>
```

To generalize this, you'd just want to change the `Skip` call to select the elements you don't want to keep:

```
doc.Root
   .Elements()
   .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("name") != "name to keep")
   .Remove();
```

Comment: thank you for new knowledge, I didn't knew that. But structure of my xml is far more complexed and I need more to narrow it by attribute Name = "The only object I need"

Comment: @ArkadiuszRaszeja: Then you should have put that in the question, instead of saying you only needed to keep the first element. I answered the question you asked, because that's all I had to work on. You should be able to adapt my answer though - just change `Skip` to a `Where` clause which selects each element you don't want to keep.

Comment: As I said, structure of my XML is quite complicated, so there is no point to select elements to remove. It's the way easier to just select what I want to keep.

Comment: @ArkadiuszRaszeja: If you want to try to do that, fine. I've given you an answer to your original question, and now an answer to the revised one, with an example. If you decide to ignore those, that's your choice... but I'd suggest that applying a single `!` character to invert from "elements to select" to "elements to remove" is pretty simple...

Comment: I know, I wasn't specific enough, my bad. However, my xml contains 40 000 lines, theres no way to select wat need to be cutted off. Furthermore I have over three houndred xml's like that, so there is possibility, that some of them will have other structure. Your further answer also Does not solve my problem, because there are elements with "Attribute" attribute inside "object" :( Anyway thanks for helping

Comment: @ArkadiuszRaszeja: I give up then. I've explained as clearly as I can how to answer the questions you've asked, and give simple solutions. I doubt that you'll find someone else able to answer your still-unclear question. I suggest you delete it, then either edit (while deleted) or ask a new question, putting more effort into being clear to avoid wasting other people's time.

Comment: @JonSkeet I love the way you explained anything. Its 100% clear and straight forward solution.